# Multicast UDP Frames_Dependent on the Gateway address? And why do I see them when I am not a part of multicast group

Tags: udp, multicast

I have a device “X” with the IP as 192.168.0.5, Subnet mask – 255.255.255.0
which is set to send the UDP multicast frames at the multicast IP – 239.0.0.0, destination port – 5001
I am directly connecting my laptop to this device – Laptop IP is 192.168.0.100
First, I do not see any multicast frames at all; I am using wireshark to monitor the network. There is no switch in between – Just my laptop running wireshark and the device “X”.
Then, when I define a Gateway address in the “X”, say 192.168.0.24 – I started seeing the UDP multicast frames on the wireshark.
My question is: 
Why is it required to define a gateway in the device “X”? Shall it not simply send the multicast UDP frames out of the port defining the multicast destination address as UDP does not require a connection to be established before the flow of data?
Also, the below frames do not mention any Gateway address, then what is the reason that the device “X’ is dependent on the gateway address:

![Wireshark Frame][1]
Is there a problem with the implementation of multicast UDP in the device?
The below questions are about the Multicast TCP/UDP Frames:
1.  Since my PC is not a part of the multicast group (239.0.0.0), it shall not see any frames which are destined for 239.0.0.0 – then why do I see the frames on wireshark? Is it because there is no mechanism to filter those frames? And if I use a switch with IGMP, I’d not see those multicast frames if my PC is not a part of 239.0.0.0?
2.  I read that the multicast IP is mapped to the layer-2 Multicast MAC. Also, I can see from the above wireshark frames that there is an IPv4_multicast MAC. Question is: How can I see a list of MAC addresses that my PC is going to accept and forward to the upper layers?
Thank you for your answers.

Can't post wireshark image as I don't have the reputation :(

Comment: I am bothered with the same question. +1

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have a multiple network interfaces and when you set the default gateway it moves that interface up in priority and that's why you start seeing packets. Check the multicast options used when you join the multicast group. You may be able to specify the network interface to join. Depending on the OS you're using you may be able to add a static route for multicast or you can try moving your multicast interface up in priority.

Comment: Thank You for your reply.Actually I am defining the gateway in the device "X" - Not in the monitoring PC. The issue apparently was I was not seeing any multicast UDP frames from the device "X" when there was no gateway IP set in it - As soon as I entered the gateway IP in device "X" (even when there was no gateway present and the entered IP  was not available in any of the connected devices), I started seeing the multicast UDP frames. So, It appears that the device "X" send out the UDP multicast frames only when there is a Gateway address defined; Else, it doesn't send out the frames.

Comment: This was my first question. I think there shall be no need to define a "Gateway" when you are sending out a multicast UDP. The device shall simply send out the multicast frames without worrying about the "Gateway". The device "X" is based on Vxworks, by the way.